# How to write generated ogg data into a webrtc audio track?

Tags: go, webrtc

I'm using Azure speech SDK to do tts and generate OGG data, I want to send the streaming output into a WebRTC audio track, I wrote this function which could send data to the peer but I can't hear the audio on the client.

What's wrong with this code and how can I get it to work?

```
func sendAudioData(data io.Reader, audioTrack *webrtc.TrackLocalStaticSample) error {
    ogg, _, oggErr := oggreader.NewWith(data)
    if oggErr != nil {
        return oggErr
    }
    var lastGranule uint64
    for {
        pageData, pageHeader, oggErr := ogg.ParseNextPage()
        if errors.Is(oggErr, io.EOF) {
            fmt.Printf("All audio pages parsed and sent")
            return nil
        }

        if oggErr != nil {
            return oggErr
        }
        slog.Info("ParseNextPage", "header", pageHeader)
        // The amount of samples is the difference between the last and current timestamp
        sampleCount := float64(pageHeader.GranulePosition - lastGranule)
        lastGranule = pageHeader.GranulePosition
        sampleDuration := time.Duration((sampleCount/48000)*1000) * time.Millisecond

        slog.Info("Write Sample", "duration", sampleDuration, "length", len(pageData))
        if oggErr = audioTrack.WriteSample(media.Sample{Data: pageData, Duration: sampleDuration}); oggErr != nil {
            return oggErr
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code to generate stream data.

```
package speech

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "time"

    "github.com/Microsoft/cognitive-services-speech-sdk-go/audio"
    "github.com/Microsoft/cognitive-services-speech-sdk-go/common"
    "github.com/Microsoft/cognitive-services-speech-sdk-go/speech"
)

func azureTTSStream(text, lang string) (*speech.AudioDataStream, error) {
    // stream, err := audio.CreatePullAudioOutputStream()
    // if err != nil {
    //  return nil, err
    // }
    // audioConfig, err := audio.NewAudioConfigFromStreamOutput(stream)
    // if err != nil {
    //  panic(err)
    // }
    speechKey := os.Getenv("AZURE_SPEECH_KEY")
    speechRegion := os.Getenv("AZURE_SPEECH_REGION")
    speechConfig, err := speech.NewSpeechConfigFromSubscription(speechKey, speechRegion)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    speechConfig.SetSpeechSynthesisOutputFormat(common.Ogg48Khz16BitMonoOpus)
    synthesizer, err := speech.NewSpeechSynthesizerFromConfig(speechConfig, nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    voice := azureVoices[lang]
    input := fmt.Sprintf(azureSAMLInput, lang, voice, text)

    task := synthesizer.SpeakSsmlAsync(input)
    var outcome speech.SpeechSynthesisOutcome
    select {
    case outcome = <-task:
    case <-time.After(60 * time.Second):
        fmt.Println("timeout")
        return nil, errors.New("timeout")
    }
    defer outcome.Close()
    if outcome.Error != nil {
        fmt.Println("outcome error: ", outcome.Error)
    }
    
    return speech.NewAudioDataStreamFromSpeechSynthesisResult(outcome.Result)

    // if outcome.Result.Reason == common.SynthesizingAudioCompleted {
    //  fmt.Println("outcome completed")
    // }

    // cancellation, _ := speech.NewCancellationDetailsFromSpeechSynthesisResult(outcome.Result)
    // msg := fmt.Sprintf("CANCELED: Reason=%d.\n", cancellation.Reason)
    // if cancellation.Reason == common.Error {
    //  fmt.Sprintf("%s ErrorCode=%d, ErrorDetails=[%s]\n", msg, cancellation.ErrorCode, cancellation.ErrorDetails)
    // }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the rest of you file please? It'd help to see which libraries you use.

Comment: @Rafet I'm using Pion for WebRTC, and https://github.com/Microsoft/cognitive-services-speech-sdk-go for TTS. I updated the code sample to include the TTS part in the question above.

Answer (score 2):

I think the main issue can be related to the maximum OPUS frame size. I did a lot of experiments and figure out that Azure text to speech API generates OGG file with page size that usually has approx. 520ms of audio data.

The code gets the whole page data with `ogg.ParseNextPage()` and then sends it as a sample using `audioTrack.WriteSample`:

```
azureSample.ogg
---------------
sendAudioData start
2023/09/01 23:12:00 INFO ParseNextPage header="&{GranulePosition:0 sig:[79 103 103 83] version:0 headerType:0 serial:1006886592 index:1 segmentsCount:1}"
2023/09/01 23:12:00 INFO Write Sample duration=0s length=47
2023/09/01 23:12:00 INFO ParseNextPage header="&{GranulePosition:24000 sig:[79 103 103 83] version:0 headerType:0 serial:1006886592 index:2 segmentsCount:25}"
2023/09/01 23:12:00 INFO Write Sample duration=500ms length=4000
2023/09/01 23:12:00 INFO ParseNextPage header="&{GranulePosition:48960 sig:[79 103 103 83] version:0 headerType:0 serial:1006886592 index:3 segmentsCount:26}"
2023/09/01 23:12:00 INFO Write Sample duration=520ms length=4160
2023/09/01 23:12:00 INFO ParseNextPage header="&{GranulePosition:73920 sig:[79 103 103 83] version:0 headerType:0 serial:1006886592 index:4 segmentsCount:26}"
2023/09/01 23:12:00 INFO Write Sample duration=520ms length=4160
2023/09/01 23:12:00 INFO ParseNextPage header="&{GranulePosition:98880 sig:[79 103 103 83] version:0 headerType:0 serial:1006886592 index:5 segmentsCount:26}"
2023/09/01 23:12:00 INFO Write Sample duration=520ms length=4160
2023/09/01 23:12:00 INFO ParseNextPage header="&{GranulePosition:123840 sig:[79 103 103 83] version:0 headerType:0 serial:1006886592 index:6 segmentsCount:26}"
2023/09/01 23:12:00 INFO Write Sample duration=520ms length=4160
2023/09/01 23:12:00 INFO ParseNextPage header="&{GranulePosition:132312 sig:[79 103 103 83] version:0 headerType:4 serial:1006886592 index:7 segmentsCount:9}"
2023/09/01 23:12:00 INFO Write Sample duration=176ms length=1440
All audio pages parsed and sent
```

According to RFC 7578 and RFC 6716 the maximum size of a packet is 120 ms:

1. [RFC 7578. RTP Payload Format for the Opus Speech and Audio Codec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7587):

> 4.2. Payload Structure The Opus encoder can output encoded frames representing 2.5, 5, 10, 20, 40, or 60 ms of speech or audio data.
> Further, an arbitrary number of frames can be combined into a packet,
> up to a maximum packet duration representing 120 ms of speech or audio
> data.

2. [RFC 6716. Definition of the Opus Audio Codec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6716)

> 2.1.4.  Frame Duration  Opus can encode frames of 2.5, 5, 10, 20, 40, or 60 ms.  It can also combine multiple frames into packets of up to
> 120 ms.
>
> 3.2.5. Code 3: A Signaled Number of Frames in the Packet  M MUST NOT be zero, and the audio duration contained within a packet MUST NOT
> exceed 120 ms
>
> [R5] Code 3 packets contain at least one frame, but no more than 120 ms of audio total.

[RFC 6716](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6716) also has a recommendation about the frame size:

> For real-time applications, sending fewer packets per second
> reduces the bitrate,    since it reduces the overhead from IP, UDP,
> and RTP headers.    However, it increases latency and sensitivity to
> packet losses, as    losing one packet constitutes a loss of a bigger
> chunk of audio.    Increasing the frame duration also slightly
> improves coding    efficiency, but the gain becomes small for frame
> sizes above 20 ms.    For this reason, 20 ms frames are a good choice
> for most    applications.

The easiest way to solve it is to convert frames sizes to 20ms. I used ffmpeg (unfortunately, I have not found any package in pure Go for such a purpose):

```
ffmpeg -i azureSample.ogg -c:a libopus -page_duration 20000 -vn azureSample20ms.ogg
```

I think there an issue in your code too. [It is recommended](https://github.com/pion/webrtc/blob/master/examples/play-from-disk/main.go#L193) to use a time.Ticker for iteration over the audio file pages. For example:

```
ticker := time.NewTicker(oggPageDuration)
for ; true; <-ticker.C {
    pageData, pageHeader, oggErr := ogg.ParseNextPage()
...
```

Also be sure that autoplay your website is not blocked in your browser.

I also tried to split pages into chunks, but it requires deep [Opus file format](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6716) and [RTP protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_Transport_Protocol) knowledge and for now I am even not sure it is possible. Looks like [pion/webrtc](https://github.com/pion/webrtc) doesn't support it.

It's also worth to mention that for converting frames sizes you can try to use [oggwriter](https://github.com/pion/webrtc/blob/master/pkg/media/oggwriter/oggwriter.go) instead of ffmpeg, but I haven't found how to change page duration. Looks like it deals only with [segments sizes and number of a segments](https://github.com/pion/webrtc/blob/master/pkg/media/oggwriter/oggwriter.go#L150) (each segment [should be 255 bytes length](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3533.txt) (except the last in the page and max. number of segments 255 also)

Also, I could recommend to use Chrome for debugging. It will provide you with a lot of information about WebRTC connection. Just open this URL: `chrome://webrtc-internals/`

If would like to learn more about WebRTC there is some additional information that can helps you in further researches:

1. [WebRTC For The Curious](https://webrtcforthecurious.com/)
2. [WebRTC servers explained](https://WebRTC%20servers%20explained)
3. [WebRTC API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API)
4. [Get started with WebRTC](https://web.dev/webrtc-basics/)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and links, I also found this 1120ms limit but I'm not sure whether it's the root cause. I tried the the ticker change beore but it didn't help in this case.

Comment: May be some other reason in your case. This is my code: [Go](https://go.dev/play/p/gy48kJ85p3Q), [HTML+JS](https://codeshare.io/9OvNz8). It works OK with 20ms samples, but not with 120ms or more (even if you change related code, constants, etc...).

Comment: btw, please also pay attention to the `-page_duration 20000` parameter in `ffmpeg` command line.

Comment: OK, so it still requires an extra step to use ffmpeg to convert the sample to 20ms.

Comment: Unfortunately, it requires. I will let you know if I find other solution.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you use the webrtc.TrackLocalStaticRTP method for speech? I noticed in your code that you're using webrtc.TrackLocalStaticSample, but that's typically employed for static audio, not speech.

RTP (Real-time Transport Protocol) is a network protocol utilized in real-time applications, which would be a more suitable solution for this case.

Here's an example of using SFU with WebSocket for real-time transmission: https://github.com/pion/example-webrtc-applications/blob/master/sfu-ws/main.go

here is another usage example that demonstrates how to handle the input track with multiple simulcast rtp streams and send them back
https://github.com/pion/webrtc/tree/1390b16097d38597308a23a4473e8eb20b9f8efd/examples/simulcast

In your code, you could replace webrtc.TrackLocalStaticSample with   webrtc.TrackLocalStaticRTP and include the following snippet to handle the format:

```
    // Convert pageData to RTP packet format
    rtpPacket := rtp.Packet{
        PayloadType:  audioTrack.PayloadType(),
        SequenceNumber: audioTrack.GetNextSequenceNumber(),
        Timestamp: uint32(pageHeader.GranulePosition),
        Payload: pageData,
    }

    // Write RTP packet to the audioTrack
    if rtpErr := audioTrack.WriteRTP(&rtpPacket); rtpErr != nil {
        return rtpErr
    }
```

For more examples of WebRTC architectures, check out:
https://medium.com/secure-meeting/webrtc-architecture-basics-p2p-sfu-mcu-and-hybrid-approaches-e2aea14c80f9

I hope I helped a little in this case.

Comment: I'm learning from this example which plays the Ogg audio from a disk file https://github.com/pion/webrtc/blob/master/examples/play-from-disk/main.go The TTS service I'm using now also has the option to generate stream ogg data, so I thought they would be similar. I'll have a try on WriteRTP, do you know what's the difference between Ogg data read from disk and Ogg data generated dynamically?

Comment: Hi @shellfly, I'm also trying to do the same thing using the play-from-disk example as a base. Have you found a way to pipe a TTS response into a WebRTC audio track?

Comment: @matthew Unfortunately, I didn't find a way to do it either